# React native mapDispatchToProps not working

Tags: react-native, redux

I can't get my mapDispatchToProps to work properly.

I export a combineReducers:

```
export default combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
  tenants: TenantsReducer
});
```

The tenants reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  error: false,
  data: [],
  tenantData: {},
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TENANTS_DATA:
      return { ...state, error: false, data: action.payload };
    case GET_TENANT_DATA:
        return { ...state, error: false, tenantData: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Then I have getTenantByID method in my action

```
export const getTenantByID = ({ tenantID }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const getTenant = {
      FirstName: 'Jonh', LastName: 'Doe', Email: 'jonh@test.com', Phone: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
      Unit: '101', MiddleName: '',
    };
    dispatch({
      type: GET_TENANT_DATA,
      payload: getTenant
    });
  };
};
```

Finally, I tried to use it in my component.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTenantByID } from '../actions';
...

componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const tenantID = navigation.getParam('tenantID', '0');
    this.props.getTenantByID(tenantID);
      console.log(this.props); 
    this.state = {
      tenantData: this.props.tenantData
    };
  }

const mapStateToProps = ({ tenants }) => {
  return {
    error: tenants.error,
    tenantData: tenants.tenantData
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
     return {
          getTenantByID
     };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TenantDetails);
```

In my componentDidMount, the console.log(this.props) is returning a empty object for tenantData. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial state is showing as the component already mounted, which is empty object {}

```
this.props.getTenantByID(tenantId);
```

this action triggers actually, but the data is not available in componentDidMount lifecycle.

**try putting log in render like this**

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getTenantByID(2);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.tenantData); // 1st render => {}, 2nd render=> desired data
    return (
      <div/>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It worked! I was trying to update my state in the componentDidMount with this.props.tenantData. I think I'll have to do it in the render() method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use componentDidUpdate to check if value is changed,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
     if(prevProps.tenantData !== this.props.tenantData){ console.log(prevProps.tenantData, this.props.tenantData) }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this example, where are you setting the getTenant data value? Looks like you removed it from the action

Comment: why are you using constant values in action?   if you are using constant values why are you passing tentantId?... anyways just add const getTenant...it'll work

Comment: I'll change it for http request later. Now, it is just a test. Anyway, it still returning an empty object for tenantData

Comment: what's getting when you console log tenantData in action.js

Comment: In the action.js it is showing the data even though before the code changing that you mentioned. Even inside the mapStateToProps, the console.log(tenants.tenantData) is showing the data

Comment: then what  is the problem actually

Comment: It's odd... The console.log(this.props.tenantData) inside the componentDidMount() is returning an empty object

Comment: just try adding an initial data for tenantData in reducers

Comment: I think I have it. Take a look in my post for the const INITIAL_STATE in my reducer

Comment: In the componentDidUpdate, prevProps.tenantData returned an empty object. this.props.tenantData returned the object with values

Answer (score 0):

remember to receive the dispatch parameter in your mapDispatchToProps method

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
      getTenantByID: (tenantID ) => {
          dispatch(getTenantByID({tenantID }));
      };
 };
};
```

call for

`this.props.getTenantByID({ tenantID: 10 })`

Comment: Still same issue. I also think in this example the dispatch is defined but never used